# AG-GRID serverside total row does not show a correct value

Tags: angular, pagination, ag-grid, server-side

I have an issue with total element count and passing it in success callback to Ag-grid.

```
createServerSideDatasource(): IServerSideDatasource {
    return {
        getRows: async params => {
            this.fetchRows({
                params: params,
            });
        },
    };
}

async fetchRows(options: Partial<IGetServerSideOptions>) {

    this.store.select(MtInsightsOverviewCustomPageState.gridItems$).subscribe(data => {
        options.params.success({
            rowData: data,
            rowCount: 80
        })
    })
}
```

and even when i set total row count manually to 80, it is still parsing element data length as row count and shows 80.

Please help, I am starting to have anxiety because of it.

below html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
class="ag-theme-balham grid"
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
[rowData]="dataTableItems | async"
[components]="components"
[pagination]="paginationService.defaultPaginationModel.enabled"
[paginationPageSize]="paginationService.defaultPaginationModel.pageSize"
(firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
(cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```